# Sorting array with numbers without sort() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm learning Javascript and I'm stuck with an exercise I found in a tutorial, I think it was learn street.com... I have to sort an array with numbers without using the sort() method. Something like this:

```
numbers =[12,10,15,11,14,13,16];
```

I have tried a lot of things since this morning but I can't find how to do this. Anyone can help? I need explanations too, not only the answer!

Thanks

Oh and see what I have at this point:

```
function ordre(liste){
var result=[];


for(i=0; i<liste.length; i++){

for(j=0; j<liste.length; j++){
        if(liste[i]>liste[j+1]){

        }
    }

 }

 console.log( result );
}

ordre(nombres);
```

Comment: What "things" have you tried, can you show us the code from your attempts? there are many algorithms available; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: Exercises aren't any good if someone else does them for you. A little research into sorting algorithms is all you need.

Comment: It sounds like the lesson is trying to teach you something about how sorting functions under the hood.  Try to increase your knowledge about the subject.  The wiki is a good suggestion as a place to start.

Comment: Yes, This is one of the classical problem in computer science. As others say go and study a sorting algorithm. May be look for bubble sort as it is relatively less complicated. First understand how it works may be use pseudo-code or animations and then implement it in your favorite language not a big deal.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look at the bubble sort algorithm...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is a [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Bubble_sort) function for you to reference, but as mentioned there are many different [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

```js
function bubbleSort(array) {
  var done = false;
  while (!done) {
    done = true;
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i += 1) {
      if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) {
        done = false;
        var tmp = array[i - 1];
        array[i - 1] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }

  return array;
}

var numbers = [12, 10, 15, 11, 14, 13, 16];
bubbleSort(numbers);
console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: If you are a beginner with sorting, bubble sort is easy to understand... If you can't explain this yourself you should probably work through the algorithm by hand until you can.  This should be VERY easy to understand once you are done.  If it isn't, study some more.

Comment: Very simple method and a good use case for the bubble sort. Just note that only good when array is relatively small.

Comment: With out tmp variable use ES6 array destructuring  [narr[i-1],narr[i]] = [narr[i],narr[i-1]] will work like a charm