# Sort a string according to number of length

Tags: javascript, sorting

Just want to ask for help to resolve my issue.

I just wanted to sort all inputted string according to least to more string

ex. aa,aaa,aaaa,a display should be a,aa,aaa,aaaa

my problem is that it doesn't sort anything

```js
function countStr() {
  var newArray = (document.getElementById("number").value);
  var n = newArray.length;
  strarr.push(newArray);
  strarrasc.push(newArray);
  strarrdsc.push(newArray);

  //count string length
  document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML = n;
  console.log(n);
  console.log(countSort_asc(n));

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = strarr;
  console.log(strarr);

  mySort_asc(strarrasc);
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = strarr;
  console.log(countSort_asc(strarrasc));

  mySort_dsc(strarrdsc);
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = strarrdsc;
  console.log(countSort_dsc(strarrdsc));
}

function countSort_asc(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < strarr.length; i++) {
    var temp = strarr[i];
    var b = i - 1;
    while (b >= 0 && strarr[b] > temp) {
      strarr[b + 1] = strarr[b];
      b--;
    }
    strarr[b + 1] = temp;
  }
  return strarr;
}

function countSort_dsc(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < strarr.length; i++) {
    var temp = strarr[i];
    var b = i - 1;
    while (b >= 0 && strarr[b] < temp) {
      strarr[b + 1] = strarr[b];
      b--;
    }
    strarr[b + 1] = temp;
  }
  return strarr;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    Input a text: <input id="number" type="text" name="number" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="countStr()">
    <div>
      count
      <p id="demo0"></p>
    </div>
  </form>
  Entered String :
  <p id="demo"></p>
  Ascending Order :
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  Descending Order :
  <p id="demo2"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: What is `strarr`? Can you fix the snippet to include it?

Comment: that is a variable where I store the inputted strings.

Comment: `var strarr = [];
 var strarrasc = [];
 var strarrdsc = [];`

Answer (score 3):

You can `split()` the string. Use `sort()` and use the `length` property in sorting. `join()` the array to form the string.

### Using `sort()`

```js
var arr = [];

function countStr() {
  var str = (document.getElementById("number").value);
  arr.push(str);
  var asc = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
  var desc = [...arr].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);

  document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML = arr.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = asc;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = desc;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    Input a text: <input id="number" type="text" name="number" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="countStr()">
    <div>
      count
      <p id="demo0"></p>
    </div>
  </form>
  Entered String :
  <p id="demo"></p>
  Ascending Order :
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  Descending Order :
  <p id="demo2"></p>

</div>
```

---

### Using Loop:

Referencing the bubble sort from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243366/sorting-array-with-numbers-without-sort-method)

```js
var newArray = [];

function countStr() {
  var newString = (document.getElementById("number").value);
  newArray.push(newString);

  //count string length
  document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML = newArray.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = newArray;

  var asc = countSort_asc(newArray);
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = asc;

  var desc = countSort_dsc(newArray);
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = desc;


}

function countSort_asc(arr) {
  arr = arr.slice(0);
  var done = false;
  while (!done) {
    done = true;
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
      if (arr[i - 1].length > arr[i].length) {
        done = false;
        var tmp = arr[i - 1];
        arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

function countSort_dsc(arr) {
  arr = arr.slice(0);
  var done = false;
  while (!done) {
    done = true;
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
      if (arr[i - 1].length < arr[i].length) {
        done = false;
        var tmp = arr[i - 1];
        arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    Input a text: <input id="number" type="text" name="number" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="countStr()">
    <div>
      count
      <p id="demo0"></p>
    </div>
  </form>
  Entered String :
  <p id="demo"></p>
  Ascending Order :
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  Descending Order :
  <p id="demo2"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: is there any way without using this function, just same as my code?

Comment: You mean, no `sort()` function just loop?

Comment: btw, is the whole string `aa,aaa,aaaa,a` entrered? or one at a time?

Comment: after hitting the enter it will be displayed one at a time and othe

Answer (score 0):

That looks to be a little bit complicated, why not just use `sort` instead?

```js
const inputArr = [];
function countStr() {
  inputArr.push(document.getElementById("number").value);
  document.getElementById("demo0").textContent = inputArr.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = inputArr;
  document.getElementById("demo1").textContent = inputArr
    .slice(0)
    .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
  document.getElementById("demo2").textContent = inputArr
    .slice(0)
    .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    Input a text: <input id="number" type="text" name="number" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="countStr()">
    <div>
      count
      <p id="demo0"></p>
    </div>
  </form>
  Entered String :
  <p id="demo"></p>
  Ascending Order :
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  Descending Order :
  <p id="demo2"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: this is an exercise for us students not to use simplified codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of strings, you can sort them by using the `sort` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
var sortedStrings = strings.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.length === b.length) { 
        return 0; 
    }

    return a.length > b.length ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: will that will be the easiest way to sort it but how about in array and looping? how can I sort it that way.

Comment: why do you want to use loops?

Comment: its part of the exercise

Comment: is the exercise to solve the problem, or come to stackoverflow to make someone give you an answer?

Comment: is to ask ask to my problem. as the given codes above .. when I input > aa,a,ab,aaa my expected outcome should be . > a,aa,ab,aaa my code problem is the output is a,aa,aaa,ab

Comment: My point is, it looks like it is part of a course. And all I'm saying, if that's the case, is you should try to solve it urself. Not ask for people to give you the solution.